# How to disable assert in gradle test

Tags: gradle, assert

I use JAVA_OPTS with disableassertions, but when `gradle test` is run, there are still outputs with `java.lang.AssertionError`. Why ?

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

apply plugin: "groovy"

dependencies {

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'  // for compile groovy
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test:3.0.5.RELEASE"
    compile "junit:junit:4.+"
}
```

`gradle test` output

```
:booking:processResources UP-TO-DATE 

:booking:classes

:booking:jar

:compileJava

:compileGroovy

:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:classes

:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:compileTestGroovy

:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE

:testClasses

:test

ScriptTester > testHandle FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError at ScriptTester.groovy:127
```

Comment: Post your gradle script.

Comment: BTY , i use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner in test case .

Comment: Do You have errors in tests?

Comment: Groovy assertions are not the same as Java assertions - you cannot turn off Groovy assertions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gradle runs tests in separate JVM(s).To set arguments for these JVMs, use:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs "...", "..."
}
```

There is a shortcut to enable or disable assertions:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    enableAssertions = false
}
```

For further API details, see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Comment: Thanks , Assert disabled now .