# Enabling assertions in Gradle/JUnit

Tags: java, gradle, junit, build.gradle, junit5

My project uses gradle and JUnit 5.01.  The JUnit assertions are working fine.  However, my regular Java assertions in the tested code itself are not firing.  I would expect a failed assert to throw an AssertionError that would be caught and reported by JUnit.

I found this: [How to disable assert in gradle test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399404/how-to-disable-assert-in-gradle-test), and so created this build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += "-Xlint:unchecked"
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    enableAssertions = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.1')
    testCompile('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.1')
}

// Define the main class for the application
mainClassName = 'CMS'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'CMS',
                   'Main-Class': 'com.brandli.cms.CMS'
    }
}

junitPlatform {
    filters {
        includeClassNamePattern '.*'
    }
}

test {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you debug your test and confirm that the assertion error is thrown?

Comment: Yes.  I put an assert false in a place where it has to be hit.  I ran the code outside of JUnit and ran it with assertions enabled (-ea) and it hit my assertion.  But running it with JUnit (the "build" gradle target) does not.  (It later hits a JUnit assertion in my test.)  So I know the code is being run without java assertions enabled.

Comment: Thank you, your question was my answer, I was looking for `testLogging { exceptionFormat = 'full' }` so it shows expected but was when any test fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging into gradle, and a lot of experimenting, led me to find that replacing

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    enableAssertions = true
}
```

with

```
junitPlatformTest {
    enableAssertions = true
}
```

did the trick.  I don't know why.

Comment: JUnit 5 is supported via plugin written by the JUnit team and not “natively” by gradle (yet). With that in mind what you found is not that surprising. There will be some issues before native support is implemented. As another gradle user, I hope this happens sooner

Comment: And for the Kotlin DSL?